# Windows Task Scheduler on File change

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, events

I am trying to synchronise my files between a *Win7 Starter* laptop and *WinXP* workstation.
As *Win7 Starter* has limited sync support, I installed *SyncToy 2.1* and it works fine. However, it requires my manually syncing the files. The help system suggests using Task Scheduler. The options of launching a task at logon/start up or every 10 min are not suitable or flexible enough. I looked at advanced trigger options and they require knowledge of Event IDs that I could not find decent info on. Hence,

in Task Scheduler, is it possible to set a trigger equivalent to 'file changed' for a specific file?

Comment: I think windows live mesh will do what you want!

www.mesh.com

Comment: @smoknheap Not what I thought of, but just what I needed! Per folder P2P sync. Thanks. Can you please turn your comment into an answer so that I can rate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think windows live mesh will do what you want! www.mesh.com

Comment: That link goes to the OneDrive from Microsoft.  That is a odd way to watch and sync imho.  Why not dropbox at that line of thinking too.

Answer (score 1):

'[FolderWatcher](http://www.folderwatcher.com/)' claims to do just what you want:

```
"Execute unlimited number of actions per folder event"
```

Price is a bit hefty for a wrapper around '[System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)'.
There are similar tools like '[WatchDirectory](http://www.watchdirectory.net/)' available which claim the same.

Comment: Comes very close to what I was looking for. Do you think I can recreate some of the functions using Task Scheduler? So far, I could not find a good reference for Event IDs.

Comment: @which of the stuff comes close? as far as i understand folderwatcher or watchdirectory: you define your actions inside these apps and autostart them (the apps) which in turn start the actions.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. The system events these two programs are wrapped around. If I knew the event IDs, I could set up the triggers in Task Scheduler to fit my purpose.

Comment: i think you mix something up. the events triggering System.IO.FileSystemWatcher are events of the operating system (or at a very deep level). the events you can pick in the schtasks-gui are logged events (as in system log).

Answer (score 1):

I have used [VisualCron](http://www.visualcron.com) for syncing files when they are created. You can set VisualCron to watch a specific folder with a Trigger and then do whatever you want with the file when it has been written completely. You can copy, FTP it or use the name and insert into database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at different file syncing solutions like Dropbox?  That would remove a lot of work on your part.  A free account is good for 2 GB, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Whilst I was not looking for an option to keep my files in the cloud, it looks very promising indeed.

Comment: My only follow up is that the nice thing about Dropbox is all your files are still stored locally. On each machine, it puts a new folder in your "My Documents" directory and all of the files are simultaneously stored on each computer. Dropbox just keeps them synced up. (Incidentally, it also stores copies that are accessible via the web.)

Comment: Have just tried it - works like magic.