# tool to copy/move files when they appear on network drive (windows)

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

I have some computers behind firewall that write their data to network drive. I'm looking for the tool that would check every minute or so and if in specific directory of network drive a new file appeared it will (on choice) move it or copy it to local directory.

The local computer is working under windows 7.

Comment: **Possible duplicate**: [Windows Task Scheduler on File change](http://superuser.com/questions/155352/windows-task-scheduler-on-file-change)

Comment: Thanks all the guys for the answer. I chose _DSynchronize_ as the simplest one. However all the tools that were listed would do the job. For this reason thumb-up for all of you and accept for nixda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FolderWatcher](http://www.folderwatcher.com/)

[WatchDirectory](http://www.watchdirectory.net/)

[VisualCRON](http://www.visualcron.com/)

Personally I don't think I would use any of these as they will be significantly "heavier weight" than just writing a `bat` script to copy files and running that script from the task scheduler on file create event.

Comment: A scheduled batch file using RoboCopy should definitely do the trick, this feels like a duplicate question but I haven't been able to find the duplicate. Meh.

Comment: Definitely bat-script, you can use either `xcopy` or `robocopy`, the latter of which also has a built-in sheduling mechanism, which will run as long as the cmd window is open, but can be saved into a job file, you can load the task from in following sessions.

Comment: After a lot of tries with DSynchronize I switched to robocopy. I couldn't get the previous one to resume work after restart of system (both via autostart or service). It's still nice tool that I use for grabbing data from remote computer in manual mode but not for creating a backup-copy on network-drive.

Answer (score 1):

Rsync is a powerful tool that would be ideal for this, except it is mainly for linux.

Follow this guide though:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/rsync-for-windows-deltacopy/

And I'm pretty sure it'll be ideal

Answer (score 1):

[DSynchronize](http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/) (scroll down) lets you choose between timer mode or real-time sync

[image]